# Actionbar (Navigation bar?) vs menubutton

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an application which runs full-screen and relies on the menu button. What I didn't realise is that devices like the Galaxy Tab use an actionbar which no longer has a menu button. My app currently loads a fragment displaying a settings menu when one touches the menu button:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    FragmentManager lFM = getSupportFragmentManager();
    SettingsDialogFragment lSettingsDialog = new SettingsDialogFragment();
    lSettingsDialog.show(lFM, "Settings");

    return false;    
}
```

I understand it is possible to add a custom icon to the action bar which when pressed could result in the same behaviour as a menu button. What I am unsure about is how to implement this.

How do I know that a device doesn't have a menu button and I need to add an icon to the action bar? It can't be as easy as checking the SDK version as apparently the actionbar was introduced in honeycomb, but my Galaxy Note runs ice cream sandwich and doesn't have an action bar (it still has a menu button). I don't want to give up any real-estate so adding buttons or menu options to my main layout isn't an option.

I just read on google developer that:

> Navigation Bar New for phones in Android 4.0, the navigation bar is
>   present only on devices that don't have the traditional hardware keys.
>   It houses the device navigation controls Back, Home, and Recents, and
>   also displays a menu for apps written for Android 2.3 or earlier.

So I tried setting the target version on my app to 8. Instead of a menu I get a button allowing me to change the screen size of my app - but no menu button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have an application which runs full-screen and relies on the menu button.

That has been a bad idea for *two years*.

> What I didn't realise is that devices like the Galaxy Tab use an actionbar which no longer has a menu button.

Such devices have been around for *two years*.

> My app currently loads a fragment displaying a settings menu when one touches the menu button

That was never an appropriate design move. Please allow the MENU button, where it exists, to behave normally, displaying an options menu on Android 1.x/2.x and triggering the action bar overflow on Android 3.0+.

> How do I know that a device doesn't have a menu button

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#hasPermanentMenuKey()

Comment: What is so wrong about a displaying a menu when a user hits the menu key? In this case I don't like a default options menu so I create something derived from a DialogFragment where instead of having "options" I can have a mix of buttons, tickboxes & a spinner to create a settings menu. The only other option I have is to either give up a portion of the screen (which I don't want) or to somehow show my menu on a tap or long press somewhere on the screen, neither of which is acceptable. Thanks for that last link - it allows me for those devices to pop-up the settings menu on hitting the back key.

Comment: @Lieuwe: "I don't like a default options menu" -- developers who pull stunts like this get ridiculed in the media, as lots of users and pundits complain about how Android developers are undisciplined slobs, incapable of creating apps that behave like the other apps on the device. "I create something derived from a DialogFragment where instead of having "options" I can have a mix of buttons, tickboxes & a spinner to create a settings menu" -- that is fine, but do not hack the MENU button to display it. Display it by an action bar item, or a button, or a gesture.

Comment: I understand your comments. On the other hand - <undisciplined slob mode> I couldn't care less how some other application on Android that I don't even use works. In this case it is my own application that only I and a few others run and I like the fact that the menu button brings up a custom menu and not a default looking options menu. If I wanted to be told what I can and can't create and how I should create it I would have done iOS. </undisciplined slob mode> I understand that that approach can sometimes lead to issues like the above - but they will just have to be fixed as they happen.

Comment: @Lieuwe: Suit yourself. Please bear in mind, though, that StackOverflow is not just a resource for you as an individual. It serves a massive community, including being the #1 support point for Android developers. When people include advice in their answer that you feel goes beyond your specific concerns, bear in mind that the answer is perhaps being written with the larger audience in mind.

Comment: Point taken - I had also already accepted your answer including telling me off for abusing the menu button like this. And although not the case here, I do find it hard sometimes to choose between the "right" thing and someone who pays us money to develop something and has other ideas.